# Prove that if $a(x) \in F[x]$ and $b(x) \in F[x]$ then $\langle a(x) \rangle = \langle b(x) \rangle$ if and only if $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are associates.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I believe I can prove the first direction:

Suppose $\langle a(x) \rangle = \langle b(x) \rangle$. Then the polynomial $a(x) \in \langle b(x) \rangle$. Thus there exists $s(x) \in F[x]$ such that $a(x) = b(x)s(x)$. Thus $b(x) \mid a(x)$. Similarly, since $\langle a(x) \rangle = \langle b(x) \rangle$, we have that $b(x) \in \langle a(x) \rangle$. So there exists a $t(x) \in F[x]$ such that $b(x) = a(x)t(x)$. Thus $a(x) \mid b(x)$. Since $b(x) \mid a(x)$ and $a(x) \mid b(x)$, the polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are associates.

I am struggling to prove the other direction. This is what I have so far:

Suppose that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are associates. Then $a(x) \mid b(x)$ and $b(x) \mid a(x)$ and so $a(x) = b(x)c(x)$ and $b(x) = a(x)d(x)$ for some $c(x), d(x) \in F[x]$. Then we know that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are constant multiples of each other, so $a(x) = cd(x)$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know how to go further to show that $\langle a(x) \rangle = \langle b(x) \rangle$ with that information. Should I be showing that $c = \pm 1$?

Comment: What is $F$? More to the point, why did you conclude that $c \in \mathbb{Z}$? (I assume here $F$ is a field).

Comment: $F$ is a field. I actually don't know why I concluded $c \in \mathbb{Z}$... I guess I thought that "$a(x)$ is a constant multiple of $b(x)$ meant that $c$ had to be in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $a(x)|b(x)$, then any multiple of $b(x)$ is also a multiple of $a(x)$. From the definition of $<b(x)>$ and $<a(x)>$, what do you conclude?

Comment: @Luiz-Corderio Since $a(x) \mid b(x)$ and $b(x) \mid a(x)$, any multiple of $b(x)$ is also a multiple of $a(x)$. Then $\langle b(x) \rangle$ is the set of all products $b(x)s(x)$ as $s(x)$ ranges over $F[x]$. Similarly, $\langle a(x) \rangle$ is the set of all products $a(x)t(x)$ as $t(x)$ ranges over $F[x]$. Thus $\langle a(x) \rangle = \langle b(x) \rangle$? Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $p\in\langle a\rangle$. Then $p=aq=bcq$, so $p\in\langle b\rangle$.

With this idea, it should be easy to complete the proof.

Comment: Oh! I see it. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

$a=bc$ tells you that $a\in\langle b\rangle$, so $\langle a\rangle\subset\langle b\rangle$. In the same way you deduce the opposite inclusion from $b=ad$.

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with specifics of $F[x]$. For any integral domain $R$ we have equality of principle ideals $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$ iff $a=bu$ for a unit $u\in R^\times$. This is because we find $a=bu$ and $b=av$ with $u,v\in R$, so $a=avu$ and $vu=1$.